# Highlighting in a web browser through function and text extraction

Tags: javascript, browser, web, highlight, highlighting

I am doing a small project that requires me to highlight inside the web browser. Is there any library in javascript or java where I can highlight inside a web browser? 
I want to highlight a certain word or a chunk of words given the text.

I know that there are some similar questions that involve C#, but I only know javascript and java. If possible, please keep the methods as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code from this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/fDznF/) is useful. The highlighter function:

```
function highLight(term,root,forElements,styleclass){
    root = root || document.querySelector('body');
    term = term instanceof Array ? term.join('|') : term;

    if (!term) {
     throw TypeError('Highlighter needs a term to highlight anything');
    }

    forElements = forElements && forElements instanceof Array 
                    ? forElements.join(',') 
                    : /string/i.test(typeof forElements) ? forElements : '*';
    styleclass = styleclass || 'highlight';

    var allDiv = root.querySelectorAll(forElements),
        re = RegExp(term,'gi'),
        highlighter = function(a){
                       return '<span class="'+styleclass+'">'+a+'</span>'
                      };

    for (var i=0; i<allDiv.length; i+=1){
        // recurse children
        if (allDiv[i].querySelectorAll(forElements).length){
            highLight.call(null,term, allDiv[i],forElements,styleclass);
        }
        // replace term(s) in text nodes
        var node = allDiv[i];
        for (node=node.firstChild; node; node=node.nextSibling) {
            if (node.nodeType===3){
                var re = RegExp(term,'gi');
                node.data = node.data.replace(re,highlighter);
            }
        }
    }
    //finally, replace all text data html encoded brackets
    root.innerHTML = root.innerHTML
                      .replace(/&lt;/gi,'<')
                      .replace(/&gt;/gi,'>');
}
```